# Not a value in projecting or not projecting MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

Which of the following is NOT the value, used in projecting or not projecting a fields?
Select one:

a.-1

b.1

c.-2

d.2

What can be the answer for above question, I don't know what it can be.
So it would be helpful if someone share some good notes on MongoDB

Comment: Have you read the [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)?

Comment: Have you tried each of the 4 options to see how they behave?